# Save value of multiselect admin magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, multiselect

I create a custom block, for create slider in front-end.
This work perfectly in admin and save in database.
[image]

Now I just add, a `groupe_id` instance of `groupe_customer`.
so lock my form :

```
     $fieldset->addField('target', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('home')->__("Target"),
        'name'  => 'sd['.$this->getSlideNumber().'][target]',
        'values'    => Mage::getModel("home/home_target")->getOptionArray()
    ));

    $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
              ->toOptionArray();

    $fieldset->addField('type_groupe_client', 'multiselect',array(
        'label'    =>  Mage::helper('home')->__('Group Customer'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('home')->__('Group Customer'),
        'name'      => 'sd['.$this->getSlideNumber().'][type_groupe_client]',
        'values'   =>  $groups,
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

When i choose multiple group customer, 
In my controller `saveAction()`, I check value of multi-select look my code : 
i do this =>

```
 $slideData['type_groupe_client'] = implode(',',$slideData['type_groupe_client']); 

    // Slider
            foreach ($this->getRequest()->getParam("sd") as $idx => $slideData) {
                $slide = Mage::getModel("home/home");
                if (isset($slideData["home_id"])) {
                    $slide->load($slideData["home_id"]);
                    if(isset($slideData["remove"])){
                        if(is_file(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $slide->getImage())){
                            unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $slide->getImage());
                        }
                        $slide->delete();
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    $slide->setCreatedAt(Zend_Date::now()->get(Zend_Date::ISO_8601));
                }

                $slideData['type_groupe_client'] = implode(',',$slideData['type_groupe_client']); 
                $slide->addData($slideData);

                if (isset($_FILES['sd'.$idx.'_image']['name']) and ( file_exists($_FILES['sd'.$idx.'_image']['tmp_name']))) {
                    $slide->setImage($this->manageImage('sd'.$idx.'_image'));
                } else {
                    $imageParams = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sd'.$idx.'_image');
                    if (isset($imageParams['delete']) && $imageParams['delete'] == 1) {
                        if(is_file(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $slide->getImage())){
                            unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $slide->getImage());
                        }
                        $slide->setImage("");
                    }
                }

                $slide->save();
            }
```

When I  `var_dump( $slideData['type_groupe_client'])`, I have so good id in string : string(7) "0,1,2,3" 
But they not save in database, just the first when I choose , in this example only 0 is save in my row.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please check database column for group id, it might be `numeric` but instead it should be `varchar`

Comment: My row in database "type_groupe_client" is varchar(255) :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this
`$slide->setData($slideData);` instead `$slide->addData($slideData);`

Comment: Ok this work, i don't understand why, before before I add the multiselect this work and save in database. why addData() dont add my new row and after i save ? and setData do this